# Example of a complex function analytic only on angular neighbourhoods

Tags: complex-analysis, examples-counterexamples, cauchy-integral-formula

Define the "small triangle" and "small ball"  to the right of $0\in \mathbb C$,
\begin{align} T(\epsilon,k) = \{ z \in \mathbb C:  |\arg z|<\epsilon , 0< \Re z < k\}  \\ C(\epsilon,k) = \{z\in \mathbb C: |z-\epsilon|<\epsilon, 0< \Re z < k\} \end{align}
Does there exist a complex function that is:

- analytic and bounded on some $T(\epsilon,k)$,
- not analytic on any $C(\epsilon,k)$, and
- cannot be analytically continued to a proper neighbourhood of $0$?

---

Remarks

- I want to ignore the counterexamples like $f(z) = z $ for $\arg < c$ and $f(z) = 0$ for $\arg \ge c$.
- Unlike smooth functions, my toolbox of anayltic functions is rather "sparse" without access to mollifiers, and I am not sure what sort of conditions I can enforce. Most of the analytic functions I know that are not entire are either not defined at some poles(meromorphic) or cannot be extended past a ball (lacunary series). With mobius transforms, this gives me examples of functions only analytic on a half plane.
- I know of functions that are analytic and bounded only on a 'sectorial neighbourhood of infinity', e.g. $\exp(-z^4)$, since  $\exp(-z^4) \to \infty$ along the rays  $$\{\Re z > 0, \arg z = \pm \pi/4\},$$ but if $|\arg z| < \epsilon \ll 1$, then $\cos(4\arg z)> c > 0$, so that
  $$ |\exp(-z^4)| = \exp(\Re(-z^4) ) = \exp(-|z|\cos(4\arg z)) ≤ \exp(-c|z|) \to 0   $$
  as $|z| \to \infty $ in the sector $\{ |\arg z| < \epsilon , \Re z > 0\}$.
  However, I am looking for a function that exhibits this behavior only a "finite distance away from the singular point".
- The function $z^{s}$ for $s\in(0,1)$ is a bounded function whose derivative is $O(1/|z|^{1-s})$ as $|z|\to 0$ from the right half plane. In fact, for any function $f$ analytic and bounded on $T(\epsilon,k)$, for any $\epsilon' < \epsilon$, [we have the Cauchy type estimate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2867207/80734),
  $$\sup_{z\in T(\epsilon',k)} |z f'(z)|  \leq C\frac{\sup_{z\in T(\epsilon,k)} |f(z)|}{\epsilon' - \epsilon}.$$
  I'm wondering if the functions $z^s$ are the "closest" I can get to achieving equality in this inequality. I am also considering if the angle is only to allow the above quantitative bound for functions that depends on $\epsilon,\epsilon'$, or if there are 'nasty' analytic functions that are *only* nice on a small triangle $T(\epsilon,k)$.

Comment: Take a function analytic $g$ on the unit disc, that have zeros in it that accumulate to all points of the unit circle. You can even take it bounded on the closed unit disc, and also smooth on the closed disc. Then conformally map $h:T(\epsilon,k)\to D$ to the unit disc $D$, and compose $f=g\circ h$. Then $f$ is analytic on $T(\epsilon,k)$ and cannot be extended beyond the boundary of $T(\epsilon,k)$. In particular it doesn't extend to $C(\epsilon,k)$ or to any neighborhood of the origin.

Comment: @spiralstotheleft Oh, Riemann mapping theorem gives me such a conformal map, right? Can $f$ be arranged to be bounded on $T(\epsilon,k)$? Maybe something like $f(z) \exp(-1/z)$?

Comment: Yes, $g$ can be even smooth on the closed unit disc. It might loose the smoothness after composing with $h$, but it will still be bounded.

Comment: @spiralstotheleft Wow, thats exactly what I'm looking for. If you could give an example for such a $g$ or provide a source, I would be more than happy to accept that as an answer.

Comment: The function defined by $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2^k}}{2^{k^2}}$ has that property.

Comment: @spiralstotheleft Oh, lacunary and decaying coefficient.  You can copy and paste your comments as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks, you've been a great help.